# Why does mariadb connection fail via docker?

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb

My docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
  database:
    build:
      context: ./database
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${DATABASE_NAME}
      - MYSQL_USER=${DATABASE_USER}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./database/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
      - ./database/data:/var/lib/mysql

  php-fpm:
    build:
      context: ./php-fpm
    depends_on:
      - database
    environment:
      - APP_ENV=${APP_ENV}
      - APP_SECRET=${APP_SECRET}
      - DATABASE_URL=mysql://${DATABASE_USER}:${DATABASE_PASSWORD}@database:3306/${DATABASE_NAME}?serverVersion=5.7
    volumes:
      - ../src:/var/www

  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - ../src:/var/www
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./nginx/sites/:/etc/nginx/sites-available
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./logs:/var/log
    depends_on:
      - php-fpm
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
```

With this .env file:

```
DATABASE_NAME=testDB
DATABASE_USER=appuser
DATABASE_PASSWORD=apppassword
DATABASE_ROOT_PASSWORD=password

APP_ENV=dev
APP_SECRET=24e17c47430bd2044a61c131c1cf6990
```

Result after i ran docker-compose build and docker-compose-up:

```
Version: '10.5.4-MariaDB-1:10.5.4+maria~focal'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
database_1  | 2020-06-25 17:13:10 3 [Warning] Aborted connection 3 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: 'symfonytestproject_php-fpm_1.symfonytestproject_default' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
```

And now the console stuck and i have to force a quit.

I tried always everything: removing volumes, rebuild volumes...
Iam very thankfull when anyone can help me with this problem.

Comment: Does your application (Symphony?) use the environment variable `DATABASE_URL`? It looks like it does not.

Comment: i added  - DATABASE_URL=127.0.0.3 but the same problem

Comment: yes, which strengthens my assumption. Is your application using the value of this environment variable?

Comment: my Dockerfile in my Database folder look like this: FROM mariadb:latest

CMD ["mysqld"]

EXPOSE 3306

Comment: Why do you think your PHP application uses the environment variable? Where does your PHP application create the mysql connection? Does it use this environment variable or does it take the connection string from somewhere else, e.g. a `config.php` file?

Comment: my plan is to create the database with docker and then connect.

Comment: This has nothing to do with docker. Your database container is not the problem. Your PHP application is. It does not use environment variables to configure the db connection string, but something else.